# Ruby on Rails - Track API calls made to 3rd party service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service-object

I have a 3rd party API service that I am interacting with, via my Rails app, and they have quite low daily limits.
Wondering what the best way to track API calls is?

- Database
- Redis
- In memory
- Other

I have a service object that makes all the calls. Just need a good way to track each call made and not go over the daily limit.

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone who stumbles across this at a later date.

so I managed to find something that works for this.

basically I use Rails Cache and set a key with a `raw: true` set.

`Rails.cache.fetch("unique_key", raw: true, expires_at: expiry_time)`

This allows me to then increment the value whenever a request to the external service is sent.

`Rails.cache.increment("unique_key")`

I also set the max daily calls as a constant

`MAX_DAILY_API_CALLS = 2000`

then used a custom error class to raise an error if the limit is reached

```
class TooManyApiCallsToday < StandardError
      def message
        Rails.logger.info "MINDBODY: There is a daily limit of #{MAX_DAILY_API_CALLS} and it has been reached. It will reset at midnight."
      end
    end
```

`raise TooManyApiCallsToday if @api_calls >= MAX_DAILY_API_CALLS`

Hope that helps.